# Two different actions in one sql query

Tags: postgresql

I have two `sql` queries. 
First one is insert:

```
insert into categories  (id, title,kind,parent_id,sort,url)  values (DEFAULT, 'test21','РАБОЧИЕ КАТЕГОРИИ','721','0', 'test21');
```

Second one is update:

```
with
t1 as (select id as _id, parent_id, url as url1, title as title1 from categories where parent_id !=0),
t2 as (select id, url as url2, title as title2 from categories where parent_id =0),
t3 as(select * from t2 INNER JOIN t1 ON (t2.id= t1.parent_id)),
t4 as(select _id, '/'||url2||'/'|| url1 as new_full_url, '/'||title2||'/'|| title1 as new_full_bc from t3),
t5 as (select _id, new_full_url, new_full_bc from t4 union select id, url2, title2 from t2)
update categories set full_bc=new_full_bc, full_url=new_full_url from t5 where categories.id=t5._id;
```

They work fine as two separate queries. But for some reason I need to connect these queries into one query, these two queries were like one query. Is that possible?

I mean that these queries are executed sequentially. First one, then the second. I need these queries to execute like one query, or, as I said, these two queries were like one query.

Comment: What do you mean with "connect" these queries? Do you want to use the inserted rows in the second query? Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some [sample data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) and the expected output based on that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any further checking if your query (please minimize it so that we could check it). Does is work for you to put the `INSERT` statement into a `WITH` clause as well?

```
WITH 
insert_data AS (--<your first query>),
t1 AS (...),
t2 AS (...),
...
UPDATE categories...
```